# Pandas: how to merge rows with previous ones if they start with a specific pattern

Tags: python, pandas

I have a very messed up dataset with url followed up by text just like this:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'URL': ['www.google.com this is fine', 'www.google.com this is also fine', 'www.google.com ', '   what the hell?']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['URL'])
```

I need everything that doesn't start with an URL to be merged with the previous row, but I am not sure how to approach the problem in python/pandas..
My desired outcome would be:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'URL': ['www.google.com this is fine', 'www.google.com this is also fine', 'www.google.com what the hell']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['URL'])
```

thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check which `URL`s start with `www`, and create a grouper from the result. Then just `join` the strings within each group as:

```
g = df.URL.str.startswith('www')
df.URL.str.strip().groupby(g.cumsum()).agg(' '.join).reset_index(drop=True)

0         www.google.com this is fine
1    www.google.com this is also fine
2       www.google.com what the hell?
Name: URL, dtype: object
```